# How do I make this Slimbox 2 script work?

Tags: javascript, css, lightbox, slimbox

I need help on how to make this slimbox 2 script work with this page? And know its something with the div and all but i cant figure it out. Please help!!

Here the page: [Gasbrassan](http://www.hugoth.com/gas/index.html)

And hers the slimbox code:

```
enter code here<div id="middle">
          <a href="images/big_Global.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="my caption">image #1</a>
       <img src="images/big_Global.jpg" rel="lightbox">
       <a rel='lightbox' title='The Gilles, one of the Belgian cultural traditions. Here at Barvaux.' href="images/big_Global.jpg"><img src="images/big_Global.jpg" alt="Gilles at Barvaux" title="The Gilles, one of the Belgian cultural traditions. Here at Barvaux." /></a>
```

It might be that the `<div id="middle">` somehow interferes with the script but how do i go on about keeping the layout and implenting the script?

Thanks in advance

alex

Comment: What isn't working?  I see a couple things potentially wrong:
1)  you might add a `/>`, instead of a `>` in the first image.
2)  there isn't a `</div>` tag.  Maybe it was accidentally omitted but if it wasn't, it's needed.

Comment: What isnt working? The whole slimbox 2 script.( the pic pops up in the middle of the page and the rest of the page turn see-thru grey)

Comment: and the </div> was accidentally omitted. =)

Comment: Managed to find out on my own...

Answer (score 0):

It was a spelling error in the .js name